# how to factor a number java

Tags: java

I need to factorize a number like 24 to 1,2,2,2,3. My method for that:

```
static int[] factorsOf (int val) {
          int index = 0;
      int []numArray = new int[index];

      System.out.println("\nThe factors of " + val + " are:");
      for(int i=1; i <= val/2; i++)
      {
          if(val % i == 0)
          {   
              numArray1 [index] = i;
              index++;
          }
      }

      return numArray;

  }
```

however, it is not working. Can anyone help me for that?

Comment: You've defined an array of zero length. You want a datastructure that can change size on the fly, like ArrayList.

Answer (score 7):

You have a few errors, you cannot create int array without size. I used array list instead.

```
static Integer[] factorsOf(int val) {
    List<Integer> numArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("\nThe factors of " + val + " are:");
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(val)); i++) {
        if (val % i == 0) {
            numArray.add(i);
            val /= i;
            System.out.print(i + ", ");
        }
    }
    numArray.add(val);
    System.out.print(val);
    return numArray.toArray(new Integer[numArray.size()]);
}
```

Full program using int[] according to your request.

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int val = 5;
        int [] result = factorsOf(val);
        System.out.println("\nThe factors of " + val + " are:");
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length && result[i] != 0; i ++){
            System.out.println(result[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    static int[] factorsOf(int val) {
        int limit = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(val));
        int [] numArray = new int[limit];
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
            if (val % i == 0) {
                numArray[index++] = i;
                val /= i;
            }
        }
        numArray[index] = val;
        return numArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int[] primeFactors(int num)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    factors.add(1);
    for (int a = 2;  num>1; )
        if (num%a==0)
        {
            factors.add(a);
            num/=a;
        }
        else
            a++;
    int[] out = new int[factors.size()];
    for (int a = 0; a < out.length; a++)
        out[a] = factors.get(a);
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking a more faster way?:

```
static int[] getFactors(int value) {
    int[] a = new int[31]; // 2^31
    int i = 0, j;
    int num = value;
    while (num % 2 == 0) {
        a[i++] = 2;
        num /= 2;
    }
    j = 3;
    while (j <= Math.sqrt(num) + 1) {
        if (num % j == 0) {
            a[i++] = j;
            num /= j;
        } else {
            j += 2;
        }
    }
    if (num > 1) {
        a[i++] = num;
    }
    int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, i);
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the approaches suggested here have 0(n) time complexity. This can be easily resolved using binary search approach with **0(log n)** time complexity.

What do you basically are looking for is called **Prime Factors** (although 1 is not considered among prime factors).

```
//finding any occurrence of the no by binary search
static int[] primeFactors(int number) {
    List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //since you wanted 1 in the res adn every no will be divided by 1;
    al.add(1); 

    for(int i = 2; i< number; i++) {
     while(number%i == 0) {
        al.add(i);
        number = number/i;
     }
  }
  if(number >2) 
     al.add(number);

  int[] res = new int[al.size()];
  for(int i=0; i<al.size(); i++)
    res[i] = al.get(i);

  return res;
}
```

Say input is 24, we keep dividing the input by 2 till all multiples of 2 are gone, the increase i to 3

Here is a link to the working code: http://tpcg.io/AWH2TJ

Answer (score 0):

A Working example

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(factorsOf(24));
}

static List<Integer> factorsOf (int val) {

      List<Integer> factors  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for(int i=1; i <= val/2; i++)
      {
          if(val % i == 0)
          {
              factors.add(i);
          }
      }

      return factors;

  }

  }
```

Comment: Nice observation. Removed it, modified the actual code to make it work. Missed out removing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rework an algorithm for working with big numbers using BigInteger class. Try this:

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;

class NumbersFactorization {
    public void printPrimeNumbers(String bigNumber) {
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(bigNumber);
        for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.TWO; i.compareTo(number) <= 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            while(number.remainder(i) == BigInteger.ZERO) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                number = number.divide(i);
             }
        }
        if (number.compareTo(BigInteger.TWO) > 0)  System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just missed one step in `if`. Following code would be correct:

```
System.out.println("\nThe factors of " + val + " are:");
```

You can take a square root of val for comparison and start iterator by value 2

```
if(val % i == 0)
{   
   numArray1 [index] = i;
   val=val/i; //add this
  index++;
}
```

but here you need to check if index is 2,it is `prime`.